# ffmpeg saves only first frame

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg

I generated rotating pictures in Python and now I want to create an animation from it using ffmpeg. But the generated video includes only the first frame (viewed in VLC) and is way to small (half the size of one png) for all 36 pictures. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

command in shell: `ffmpeg -framerate 5 -i "./mov/movie%03d.png" -y "movie.mp4"`

Files in Folder `mov`:

- `movie000.png`
- `movie010.png`
- ..
- `movie350.png`

`ffmpeg` version f`fmpeg-20170620-ae6f6d4-win64-static`

output

```
ffmpeg version N-86537-gae6f6d4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --e
nable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --
enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv
--enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-li
bfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug -
-enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enabl
e-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-li
bsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolam
e --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx
 --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable
-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 66.100 / 55. 66.100
  libavcodec     57. 99.100 / 57. 99.100
  libavformat    57. 73.100 / 57. 73.100
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 94.100 /  6. 94.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Input #0, image2, from './mov/movie%03d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1152x864 [SAR 2834:2834 DAR 4:3], 5 tbr,
5 tbn, 5 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
No pixel format specified, yuv444p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 00000000003ec140] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 00000000003ec140] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 00000000003ec140] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.2, 4:4:4 8-b
it
[libx264 @ 00000000003ec140] 264 - core 150 r2833 df79067 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
ec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r
ef=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
p=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decim
ate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_a
dapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=5
scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60
qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'movie.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.73.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv444p, 1152x8
64 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 5 fps, 10240 tbn, 5 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.99.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=23.0 Lsize=      19kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=1581142.9kb
its/s speed=0.00138x
video:18kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing ov
erhead: 4.403838%
[libx264 @ 00000000003ec140] frame I:1     Avg QP:17.26  size: 17865
[libx264 @ 00000000003ec140] mb I  I16..4: 29.6% 56.0% 14.5%
[libx264 @ 00000000003ec140] 8x8 transform intra:56.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000003ec140] coded y,u,v intra: 11.5% 2.3% 6.3%
[libx264 @ 00000000003ec140] i16 v,h,dc,p: 77% 22%  1%  0%
[libx264 @ 00000000003ec140] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 33%  3% 62%  0%  0%
 0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 00000000003ec140] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 53% 25% 12%  1%  1%
 2%  1%  2%  1%
[libx264 @ 00000000003ec140] kb/s:714.60
```

Comment: ffmpeg tag: "FFmpeg is a free, open source project that produces libraries and programs for handling multimedia data. Questions here should involve programmatic use of the libraries, API, or tools. Questions about interactive use of the FFmpeg command line tool should be asked on Super User or Video Production.". Voting to close (good question though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use

> Files in Folder mov: movie000.png movie010.png .. movie350.png

However, ffmpeg requires 0001,0002,0003,0004,... (contiguous)

Comment: thank you, this was the solution (consecutive numbers). However the format is specified in the command, therefore 000, 001, 002, ... is also fine :)